# How to solve general wave equation and dispersion relation using Fourier series?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, linear-algebra, differential-equations

In [this](https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/18/8/083047) paper (open access), the authors used Fourier series with most general wave equation to find the dispersion relation. I am presenting some main equations as snippets to depict their solution. We want to solve for $u(x,t)$ in the following wave equation (Eq. (1) in the paper):

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[ E(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,t) \right]-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[ \rho(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(x,t) \right]=0\tag{1}
\end{equation}

So we expand or represent the quantities using Fourier series:

$$ E(x,t)=\sum_{p=-\infty}^\infty E_{p}e^{ip(\omega_mt-k_mx)} $$
and
$$ \rho(x,t)=\sum_{p=-\infty}^\infty \rho_{p}e^{ip(\omega_mt-k_mx)} $$
both having periodicty of $\omega_m$ and $k_m$ for time and space.
Now we assume a general solution (Floquet form) for $u(x,t)$ as:

$$ u(x,t)=e^{i(\omega t-kx)} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty u_{n}e^{in(\omega_mt-k_mx)} $$

and plug everything in the wave-equation. The authors say that using orthogonality we directly have the equation (9 in the paper)

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty [(k+nk_m)(k+pk_m)]E_{p-n}u_n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty [(\omega+n\omega_m)(\omega+p\omega_m)]\rho_{p-n}u_n\tag{9}$$

Furthermore they say that it can be "**recast**" in the form (11 in paper)
$$ (\omega^2 \hat{L}_2 + \omega \hat{L}_1 +\omega \hat{L}_0)\vec{u}=0 \tag{11}$$
which is a matrix equation in $\vec{u}$  and connects $u_n$, $u_{n−1}$, and $u_{n+1}$.

I have the following questions:

(a) How to reach Eq. (9) using orthogonality?

(b) How Eqn. (9) can be cast in Eq. (11) form given that Eq. (9) does not have a relation between $u_n$, $u_{n−1}$, and $u_{n+1}$? It only has two independent sums on both sides. They do not have different phases on both side to shift a phase term and take common summation to relate these.

Please show me steps to reach Eq. (9) and then Eq. (11) from there.

Comment: Is this in 1+1D?

Comment: Yes @Qmechanic it is.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does the paper first explicitly mention 1+1D?

Comment: It is already implied, isn't it? Until it is explicitly mentioned that it is not in 1+1D.

Comment: Moreover the coordinate $x$ is simply denoted as a scalar in the notation all over, strictly implying it is the case of 1D space. Else they would have used $(x,y,z)$ or $\vec{r}$ or $\vec{x}$.